# Use google "Speak Now" in C#

Tags: c#, google-chrome, google-voice

Recently google announced a feature in Chrome browser to search text or translate texts using microphone.

http://www.seroundtable.com/google-search-speak-now-13346.html

I'd like to develop a C# desktop application to send voice to google and get the results back.
How can it be done?

Comment: @nathan I already corrected it, let's wait for it to be approved :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google does not have a speech recognition API for desktops. They only have a speech recognition API for Android developers. However, you can download Microsoft's speech recognition API here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms723627(v=vs.85).aspx and you can read how to get it to work in C# here: http://windowscoding.com/blogs/blake/archive/2006/11/01/How-to-use-Microsofts-Speech-API-in-a-managed-application.aspx

Once you run the recognition api on the sample of text you want to recognize, you can simply call google.com with the "q" parameter to do a query search

Note too that Microsoft is not the only company with a speech recognition API. You are free to use any you want.

Comment: poor microsoft.  having its own api's used against them.