# Google/Apple Voice Recognition on Dektop Applications?

Tags: c#, android, desktop-application, voice-recognition

I've checked out the speech framework that Microsoft offers in C# and it appears to be VERY bad compared to other voice recognition solutions like Siri on iPhone4 or Google's search option on my Galaxy Tab. I guess these work better as they have a HUGE amount of voice samples and it is being processed on high performance servers.

So I've been looking for their API but it doesn't seem to support desktop applications at all. The only think I could find was this post: [Use google "Speak Now" in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6446341/use-google-speak-now-in-c-sharp)

---

*----> I misunderstood what the person answering meant so this part is invalid!*

> Where the answer simply says: "Once you run the recognition api on the
>   sample of text you want to recognize, you can simply call google.com
>   with the "q" parameter to do a query search"
>
> I don't understand what he means but I do know that he claims you can
>   get a desktop API to use Google as processor. That would be great!

---

So my question is: How can I use google.com's "Speak now" Voice Recognition feature I see on my tablet, in a standalone desktop application preferably written in C#?

Comment: It's very possible that I'm reading it wrong, but it seems like the poster you're referring to means that you can use Microsoft's voice recognition API (or any other voice API) to do a simple Google search via google.com, not that you can use it to access Google's voice recognition API.  Maybe you already understood that, but I couldn't tell from your question.

Comment: I did not understand it that way, this makes this question even harder to answer. Thanks for your comment!